# disable animations wpf application wide?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Is there a way to disable all animations in a wpf application in a simple way as opposed to manually finding all animations and disabling them?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It wouldn't be safe to do so anyways. Animations aren't just for making things look pretty, they often have significant impact on the UI like making things visible/hidden.